# Where to put mobile platform inverse kinematics

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am putting a place a mobile robot with mecanum wheels. For my robot to be driven I would like to be able to specify a desired velocity to the platform (a twist) and have the robot decide itself about the velocity of the wheels (joint velocity) that lead to this desired twist: this is what I call the mobile platform's IK. This IK is not so complex to compute but I am afraid I do not understand where to perform the computation in ROS. So what is the best practise to implement this mobile IK? And where should I put the code?

I had a look at the husky packages but could not find anything relevant. I am pretty sure many robot simulations do have the same need and implement this, no?

Anyone having a better understanding than me? Any example code?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192884/where-to-put-mobile-platform-inverse-kinematics/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For most robots that include a mobile base, a robot (or mobile base) specific *driver* package is created, which includes functionality like you describe. The husky packages are examples of this.

For a more generic, plugin, type approach you might take a look at the recently announced [diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller) for [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_controllers).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-09-18**:
Hum, this is a good start, I'll dig in this direction... Thanks Gijs ;)